# div disappears when you click on select field

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

On this site in every IE - when you hover on the advanced job search a menu shows. You can input information into text field and div stays but when you click on the select menus, the div disappears. Can anyone tell me why. Most of the code comes from the backend in the CMS and I have only control on the frontend part.

http://jobs.nuance.com/

thanks

Comment: I have a general idea. I noticed that it happens because you have a `mouseLeave` event for the popup. So when you are hovering over the popped up list, IE doesn't know you're still hovering over the original `div` with the advanced search options.

Comment: What's the script that makes the box popup? Css or jquery? Please post the relative code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not seeing the mouseLeave in the code.

Comment: The dropdown for the advanced jobs link is all css based.

Answer (score 1):

**Without knowing your code, I'll take a stab at it.**

I found the following in your CSS on your `4955.css` file, line `594`:

```
.advancedsearchtigger:hover .advancedSearch {
    display:block;
}
```

Modify the `hover` property of your CSS. When the options dropdown pops up, the `focus` is no longer on either `.advancedsearchtigger` or `.advancedsearch`, so the whole box stops displaying. **IE** has a terrible track record of managing the **DOM**.

I don't know how with over **20,000** lines of code to paw through, but that's likely your culprit.